# How can I get past a 502 proxy error when uploading a file via JMeter?

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, upload, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to set up JMeter 5.5 to upload a file into our system as if it were happening in the user interface, but I continue to get a 502 proxy error. How can I get the file to upload successfully?

I am using the parameter hivUpload. If I change the parameter from hivUpload to anything else, I get a 500 error instead of a 502, so I think hivUpload is the correct parameter.

I have the file in the JMeter bin folder, but it's not clear if I need to include the full file path or not. I have tried it both ways, and neither has been successful.

[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weV0U.png)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnRJY.png)

[Source file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5S4f.png)

Request

```
POST https://cdc-ew.lutherhq1b.int/rest/v1/upload

POST data:
--s6kF9JKRBTVi1qsnV4rm1hbf6gd6HMeH62
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hivUpload"; filename="AgencyInfo 2_0 - good file.xml"
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--s6kF9JKRBTVi1qsnV4rm1hbf6gd6HMeH62--


[no cookies]
```

Response

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request<p>Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>
```

I am able to get other processes to happen successfully by sending in a JSON request as if I were doing data entry. Note the successful green entries in the results, so I believe all of the other items are set up correctly. However, we have not tried using JMeter to upload files before. I know it is possible to do this I have seen articles about it (like this one [https://artoftesting.com/fileuploadinjmeter#:~:text=File%20upload%20in%20JMeter%20will,checkbox%20in%20HTTP%20Request%20sampler.](https://artoftesting.com/fileuploadinjmeter#:%7E:text=File%20upload%20in%20JMeter%20will,checkbox%20in%20HTTP%20Request%20sampler.)), but it's not clear to me what I need to tweak in my setup.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot comment on your configuration because we don't know how exactly the file needs to be supplied as there are multiple ways of uploading the file.

You could try just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just make sure that the file you're uploading will be in "bin" folder of JMeter installation, only this way JMeter will be able to intercept the request and generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you at least tell me if I need to include the full path to the file if it's already in the bin folder?

Comment: It's not recommended to use full paths, always go for relative, if it's in "bin" folder use just file name

Comment: Well, I removed the folder names and just used the file name since it's in the bin folder. Unfortunately, that didn't work either.